# How to define let variable based on unresolved variable in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, refactoring

Quite recently we changed to `ECMAScript 6` and started to use `let` and `const` instead of `var`. After changing the settings in Intellij IDEA it started to recognize `var` variables, highlight them and offer to change to `let`:

[image: Var to Let hint]

However, when it happens that I have `unresolved variable`:

[image: unresolved variable]

and I would like to define new variable I get `var` variable instead of `let` or `const`:

[image: variable definition]

***Question: how can I define `let`/`const` instead of `var`?***

Comment: Just a note, but you should probably default to `const` not `let`. Only use `let` for variables that need to be modified, like an iterator, or `let sum = 0;`. Most variables don't need to be modified later so you should use `const` to indicate to a reader that the value they see being assigned to it is definitely still the same value later on where they might want to use that variable.

Comment: Yes, I can agree with this, thanks.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 2018.1.6 this is already not a problem, it seems that this bug was fixed.

However, it is interesting to see this hint

[image]

with this result.

[image]

Moreover, this result appears only when *use strict* is not defined in the function. In case it is defined we get the same result as described in the question.